Python flask_socketio + pty recieve handler not being called
So, I have some code for a flask_socketio virtual console. I can see the output, but when to send in a command, recv isn't called.
Code:
@socketio.on('connect')
def test_connect(auth: str):
    def read_handler(fd: int):
        emit('data', os.read(fd, 1024), broadcast=True)
    def write_handler(fd: int):
        @socketio.on('data')
        def recv(data: str):
            emit('data', data, broadcast=True)
            os.write(fd, data.encode())
    print('connect', auth)
    pty.spawn("/bin/sh", read_handler, write_handler)
    #disconnect(auth)


You can't have a Flask-SocketIO handler in a subprocess. The handlers have to be in the same process as the server. When you put your @socketio.on decorator on a function that is in the subprocess you are just registering the handler on a copied Socket.IO instance that isn't active.

Huh? I'm spawning /bin/sh, not forking.

I'm going to repeat what I said above. You cannot have Socket.IO handlers in a process other than the server itself. This has nothing to do with spawning vs forking, both create subprocesses. It just does not work.

Could you explain where this magical second process is?

You are starting a subprocess here, are you not? I'm not really sure what are you asking. I suggest you look at Socket.IO examples in Python (not in JavaScript) to learn how handlers are defined. There is plenty of them in the python-socketio and flask-socketio repositories. If you want the simplified version, 1) don't write your entire program in the connect handler, 2) don't define Socket.IO handlers inside functions and 3) don't call any Socket.IO functions from a subprocess (or if you do, do it properly, ie see the docs on using external processes).
